# how can i print the link of a directory in php?

Tags: php, mysql

i ve a word document in my folder, whose name is already inserted in the database.. i want to show the document from the folder via php.. like if someone clicks on the link, the whole document should appear in front end ..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE city LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
echo 'fast name: ' .$row['fname'];  
echo '<br /> Resume : '.$row['resume'];
```

This will only print the resume name stored in the db .. i want to represent the resume name as a link , after clicking on that it should show the whole document

Comment: <a href="path/<?php echo $row['resume'] ?>">Resume</a>

Comment: in the place of path should i give my folder link ??

Comment: Yes. Put your folder path there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you in comment, you need to put folder path in anchor tag.

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/../resume_folder/";
echo $path;
```

If `$path` is correct then write your code as below:-

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
  echo 'fast name: ' .$row['fname'];  
  echo "<a href='$path.{$row['resume']}'>Resume</a>";
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: echo '<br /> <a href="../resume/<?php echo $row[resume] ?>">Resume</a>';     i used this .. it's giving me the link but it's not fetching the resume from the folder .. as the resume has been saved in ms word format

Comment: have you do echo $path?? please check path is correct or not?

Comment: Tell me your browser and echo $row['resume'] output.

Comment: its redirecting .. and the document is in ms word.. so no problem to download it .. i m using chrome

Comment: $path=realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/resume/'.$row['resume']);

echo $path;  
echo "<a href='".$path."' target='_blank'>View Resume</a>"; i used this.. still now show

Comment: Is your link 100% correct??
Do echo $path and put that link directly into browser.

Comment: $path="resume/".$row['resume'];  
echo "<a href='".$path."' target='_blank'>View Resume</a>"; it worked ..

Comment: One of the best way for debug related to documents is echo the path and put that link directly into browser. So chrome will automatically download it and you know that link is working fine :-)

Comment: Brother if your problem is resolved then accept the answer.  So future visitors can find it as useful :-)

Comment: ohh!! Really sorry "Sister" and Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
echo '<br /> <a href = "<?php echo base_url().$row['resume'];?>"> Resume </a>';
```

Comment: @user2822250  if you use codeigniter  the base_url function get the current base path . if your  code in core php then use your path .

Comment: i ll love to learn codeigniter .. but no scope n got tired of core php aready ;9

Comment: @user2822250 if you want to know  you can talk with me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105239/personal-chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105240/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-user2822250).